# What does Cobertura instrumenting actually do?

Tags: java, instrumentation, cobertura

Can someone explain in detail what Cobertura instrumenting actually do with the byte code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It adds a callback to every line of code which tells the framework that the line was reached. For example:

```
void foo() {
  System.out.println("foo");
}
```

becomes

```
void foo() {
  Coberura.reached(<method foo, line 1>);
  System.out.println("foo");
}
```

This way, after running the unit tests, Cobertura can tell what lines were reached.